# mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

im sending data from my android application to mySQL in localhost and I receive warning on (Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, Boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatest.php on line 17)

despite the warning i'm still able insert the data into the database.

i'm wondering is it ok to ignore this or how can i solve this problem?

i tried various forums and website by none solve my problems.

```
<?php 
$dbcnx = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = "agentdatabase";
mysql_select_db($db, $dbcnx);
$user_id=$_POST['username'];
$passwd=$_POST['password'];
$query = "INSERT INTO agentable (username,password) VALUES ('".$user_id."','".$passwd."')";
echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("<b>Query failed:</b> " . mysql_error());

if($result){
    echo '<br />','pass';
}
else echo mysql_error();

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: That's... not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't free the result of an `INSERT` query, since you [can't free a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues).

Comment: Imperialist lies. Free the booleans now!

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_free_result()` only needs to be called if you are concerned about how much memory is being used for queries that return large result sets.

mysql  extension is deprecated, instead use  the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL.

mysql_query() only returns a resource for SELECT, SHOW, EXPLAIN, and DESCRIBE queries.

Answer (score 2):

Side note, the MySQL PHP extension is deprecated. It's better to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible reason that I tested and was able to reproduce this error in two other different ways which have not been mentioned here.

1)   **Your SQL has the wrong syntax** and looks like this (notice the **incorrect extra comma** after **field3**:

"select field1, field2, **field3,** from myTable";

2)   **Your SQL contains a duplicate field** and looks like this:

"select field1, **field2**, **field2** from myTable";

In both cases I got the message and it was displayed in different functions:

***"Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"***

***"Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"***

***"Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"***

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if (is_bool($result) === false) {
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```